# Postgres Explain buffers - application memory usage

Tags: node.js, postgresql, memory-leaks

I am new to the Postgres database, I read about the buffer "explain" in the Postgres database, and I read the below about it :

There are three prefixes:

- Shared blocks contain data from normal tables and indexes.
- Temp blocks contain short-term data used to calculate hashes, sorts, materialize operations, and similar.
- Local blocks contain data from temporary tables and indexes (yes, this is quite confusing, given that there is also a prefix “Temp”).

And there are four suffixes:

- Hit means that the block was found in the Postgres buffer cache.
- Read blocks were missed in the Postgres buffer cache and had to be read from the disk or the operating system cache.
- Dirtied blocks have been modified by the query.
- Written blocks have been evicted from the cache.

My question and issue: I am trying to understand the effect of buffers with all types when running queries on the application (like node js application), what buffers types can cause increasing the application memory (RAM)?

Comment: None of them.  The application memory is the application's concern, not the database server's concern.  Maybe your application comes with a memory profiler.

Answer (score 2):

All of the buffers mentioned are allocated and used on the Postgres server. The application that sent the SQL doesn't know anything about those buffers.

The code that sends the SQL to the database server (e.g. JavaScript from within Node.js) only needs to manage the RAM for the *result* of the query (which might be zero for a DML statement or really huge if the query retrieves millions of rows). But that is totally independent of the memory the database server (Postgres) manages